# Does your APEX rating impact anything in the single player mode?

Tags: mass-effect-andromeda

Obviously I'm not talking about core game mechanic wise like galactic readiness in Mass Effect 3, as I would have expected that to be a little more obvious if it were the case.

However, since the APEX strike teams are introduced in the single player I was wondering does your APEX rating impact anything in the single player mode?

Comment: So far, the only interaction I've seen between MP and SP are the rewards you can collect from the rightmost tab on the strike team interface.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

APEX rating seems to have no effect in Mass Effect Andromeda as it stands. Unlike Mass Effect 3 the final mission is not influenced by APEX rating but only the outcome of quests and tasks within the game.

No other missions are unlocked by having a higher APEX rating.